# Dropbox Drop-In Saver not working: Received non-200 response status 503 from server

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently working on a small private project which allows me to upload pictures to a website. A feature which I want to implement is to allow visitors to easily add the images to their Dropbox.

Because this is only a minor feature, I do not wish to implement the full-blown Dropbox-API, and after a bit of research I found the Dropbox Drop-Ins, which seem to be exactly what I was looking for.

I have implemented this after the instructions from the Dropbox-Site: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver#javascript

I use the following code to add my images to the Dropbox:

```
Dropbox.save({
    files: dbFiles,
    success: function() {dropboxSuccess();},
    progress: function(progress) {dropboxProgress(progress);},
    cancel: function() {dropboxCancel();},
    error: function(errmsg) {dropboxError(errmsg);}
});
```

where dbFiles is a simple array with the neccessary objects.

Basically, I think that it is working: A popup appears where I have to login or, if I'm logged in, choose a location in my Dropbox to add the pictures.

However, the following error gets thrown shortly after:

"Received non-200 response status 503 from server"

This is all information that is returned!

I have tried a lot of things, but nothings helps.

Here is the page where I implemented it:
http://thetrip.fnovy.com/dropbox.php

Errors get logged to the console.

I couldn't find any information regarding errors for this Drop-Ins, neither at the Dropbox-Site nor via search engines.

Comment: This is explained in the dropbox API docs.  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

Comment: @RayNicholus No it isn't. :-) This question is about the Saver.

Comment: And the "saver" doesn't use the core dropbox API?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Correct, the Saver doesn't use the Core API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check your URLs and how they're being redirected. For example, the first URL on your page, `http://phototrip.fnovy.com/uploads/images/2013-08-12_Test_File.png`, is responding with a 302 redirect to `http://phototrip.fnovy.comuploads/images/2013-08-12_Test_File.png`, which is, naturally, not resolving. :-)

I *believe* that the 503 is a somewhat misleading interpretation of the real problem, which is that the domain doesn't resolve. I'll update this answer if I learn more about that.

**EDIT** Confirmed that you see a 503 when the domain doesn't exist. We may be able to give a clearer error message for that, and I also hope we can give the URL in the error message so it's easier to see which URL is causing the problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Oh god, I feel really dumb now! Forgot to change the URL to the current subdomain. And I haven't made the connection between the error message and the error! Works now. Thanks!